# Condition on random variable $Y$ such that $P(XY>\epsilon) \le P(X>\epsilon)$.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Suppose we have two non negative random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are not independent. Choose some $\epsilon>0$. Do there exist some conditions on $Y$ such that
$$
P(XY>\epsilon) \le P(X>\epsilon).
$$
The most obvious condition would be that $Y\le1$ almost surely, but I am interested in less strict conditions, if possible.